# jqGrid, changes made to rows don't persist when changing pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, multi-select

So I've made this jqGrid, that loads information from an external database, in which users can select rows using multiselect but the changes made to the amount field (a drop down selection field in the grid) don't persist when changing pages. The selection on the other hand persists when changing pages. How do I get the changes made in the amount field to persist when changing pages?

edit: saving the selected fields does not seem to work as planned either, clicking save only saves the selected fields on the page the user is on. the selected fields on the other pages are not saved with it.

Below I have included a code chunk from my jqGrid.

Thanks in advance

```
var selectedRows = {};

    $('#addOffConfItemGrid').jqGrid({
       url: '/includes/functions/search/itemSearch.php?action=findItem',
       datatype : 'json',
       colNames: ['Art No', 'Omschrijving', 'Aantal','Prijs p/s'],
       colModel: [
            {name: 'ItemSearchCode', width: 65, sortable: false, search: true, align: "left", },
            {name: 'ItemDescription', width: 120, sortable: false, search: true, align: "left"},
            {name: 'amount',width:40, sortable: false, search:false,align:"left",sorttype:"center",editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{ value:GetDValues()},editrules:{required:true}},
            {name: 'ItemSalesPrice', width: 45, sortable: false, search: false, align: "right"},
        ],
       filter: true, 
       pager: 'addOffConfItemGridPager',
       onSelectAll: function(rowIds, status) {
           if (status === true) {
               for(var i = 0; i < rowIds.length; i++) {
                   selectedRows[rowIds[i]] = true;
               }
           } else {
               for (var i = 0; i < rowIds.length; i++) {
                   delete selectedRows[rowIds[i]];
               }
           }
       },
       onSelectRow: function(rowId, status) {
           if (status === false) {
               delete selectedRows[rowId];
               jQuery('#addOffConfItemGrid').jqGrid('editRow',rowId,false);
           } else {
               selectedRows[rowId] = status;
               jQuery('#addOffConfItemGrid').jqGrid('editRow',rowId,true);
           }
       },
       scrollOffset: 0,
       gridview: true,
       viewrecords: true,
       recreateFilter: true,
       emptyrecords: "Geen records gevonden",
       width: '730', 
       rowNum: 21,
       height: "auto",
       multiselect: true,
       gridComplete: function() {
           for (var rowId in selectedRows){
               $('#addOffConfItemGrid').setSelection(rowId, true);
           }
       }
    });
```